# Is it safe to put in secrets inside Google App Script code?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm creating a Google Workspace Add-On and need to make some requests using OAuth. They provide a guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services) explaining how to do so. In the sample code, it's suggested that the OAuth client secret be inline:

```js
function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('SERVICE_NAME')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('SERVICE_AUTH_URL')
      .setTokenUrl('SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL')
      .setClientId('CLIENT_ID')
      .setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET')
      .setScope('SERVICE_SCOPE_REQUESTS')
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

Is this safe for me to do?

I don't know how Google App Script is architected so I don't have details on where and how the code is being run.

Comment: I would embed them in Properties Service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it is safe since the script is only accessible to the script owner and Workspace Admins if it is for Google workspace (which may or may not be an issue).

Well, you can add some security/safety by making use of a container, by using Container-bound script which makes use of Google Spreadsheet, Google Doc or any other that allows user interaction. Or a standalone script but also makes use of other way to connect to UI for interaction. Refer to this link for more detailed explanation on that: [What is the appropriate way to manage API secrets within a Google Apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197620/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-manage-api-secrets-within-a-google-apps-script)

Otherwise, the only way I see that you can do is store the keys and secrets in User Properties. Here's how you can do it: [Storing API Keys and secrets in Google AppScript user property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540618/storing-api-keys-and-secrets-in-google-appscript-user-property)

Also you can refer to this link below for more general information on how you can manage or add some security: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control