# sharing secrets in apps scripts

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Apps Scripts inside a Google Spreadsheet that contains several API calls that needs to be authorized.
I have developed a basic interface to insert the Authorization token to these API calls and I retrieve this token via PropertiesService.getUserProperties() call.

The problem is that when I share the Google Spreadsheet link with someone the functions that make use of those API are still working. I was assuming that every user different than me should have provied his credentials in order to make those functions work as per by this documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties .

What am I missing ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540618/storing-api-keys-and-secrets-in-google-appscript-user-property

Comment: @Kos no, it does not solve my question, already read

Comment: check this (docs]https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser]: > `If the script is running under an installable trigger, this returns the account of the user who created the trigger.`

Comment: Add a [mcve] showing how the Properties service are used in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Installable triggers are the only way, another user has access to your user properties. It is mentioned in the duplicate. Also, note that there's a proper [etiquette](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i) to dispute a duplicate. You have to clearly explain why it doesn't answer your question.